# Read from array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I am trying to pull UserID from below array but I am getting this message:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: profile_picture
Filename: views/profile_view.php
Line Number: 52
```

Array:

```
array (size=1)
  'profile_picture' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[21]
          public 'UserID' => string '43' (length=2)
          public 'PictProfFlag' => string '1' (length=1)
          public 'PictPath' => string 'http://cms/uploads/category_icon.png' (length=36)
```

This is how I print it:

```
            foreach($profile_picture as $row)
            {
                echo $row->UserID;
            }
```

I am using Codeigniter Framework.

Please help

Comment: Are you sure it's not something like: `foreach($array['profile_picture'] as $row) {`?

Comment: Could you explain us what is $profile_picture ?

Comment: Can you show the code before you get to your loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just solved my problem.

I was retrieving data from model like:

Controller:

```
$this->get_user_pictures($id);
```

Model:

```
$data['profile_picture'] = $this->profile_model->picture($id);
```

And Returning array $data instead of $data['profile_picture']

It works now, thanks

Comment: how other people will understand you need this solution from your question?You should not put this answer because the answer is not related with the question. You could put it as comment that you have solved it.